# How to re-render only specific item in the List

Tags: flutter

I have a list of users. I showed it in a ListView.builder().

```
GetX<DemoGetxRebuildController>(
    builder: (_) {
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: controller.usersUI.length,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          final item = controller.usersUI[index];

          return ItemW(item: item);
        },
      );
    },
  ),
```

and ItemW:

```
class ItemW extends GetView<DemoGetxRebuildController> {
  const ItemW({
    super.key,
    required this.item,
  });

  final User item;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.grey[200],
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Column(
            children: [
              Text('${item.firstName} ${item.lastName}'),
              Text('${item.id}'),
              Text(
                '${DateTime.now()}',
                style: const TextStyle(
                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 111, 139, 112),
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 10),
            ],
          ),
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              final itemUpdate = User(
                id: item.id,
                firstName: item.firstName,
                lastName: '${item.lastName} 1',
                countryCode: item.countryCode,
                companyId: item.companyId,
              );
              controller.updateUser(itemUpdate);
            },
            icon: const Icon(Icons.update),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

updateUser function:

```
void updateUser(User user) {
    final index = usersUI.indexWhere((element) => element.id == user.id);
    if (index != -1) {
      usersUI[index] = user;
    }
  }
```

Expected: When I pressed the button on each itemUI => only the item re-render and the whole of the list, not re-render (I'm checking by ${DateTime.now()} in the Text widget)

Actual: When I pressed the button on each itemUI => the whole of the list re-rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a minimal code where only a particular widget rebuilds when the user taps it. In this code, the build() method will only called once.

I don't use any third-party library here. You can easily understand how the thing works. In this case, I divide the widget into a separate class.

Try to understand what I did in the code. Provide me acknowledgement for same. If you're still confused? Feel free to provide feedback in the comments.

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Flutter Demo",
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final List<User> usersList = <User>[
    User(id: 1, name: "A", tapCount: 0),
    User(id: 2, name: "B", tapCount: 0),
    User(id: 3, name: "C", tapCount: 0),
    User(id: 4, name: "D", tapCount: 0),
    User(id: 5, name: "E", tapCount: 0),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This build() method will only called once.
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: usersList.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            final User user = usersList[index];

            // Only the below-mentioned  part will rebuild its state.
            return ItemAdapter(user: user);
            // Only the above-mentioned  part will rebuild its state.
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ItemAdapter extends StatefulWidget {
  const ItemAdapter({required this.user, super.key});
  final User user;

  @override
  State<ItemAdapter> createState() => _ItemAdapterState();
}

class _ItemAdapterState extends State<ItemAdapter> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text("Name: ${widget.user.name}"),
      subtitle: Text("Tap count: ${widget.user.tapCount}"),
      onTap: () {
        widget.user.tapCount = widget.user.tapCount + 1;
        // Here, only rebuilding a particular widget.
        setState(() {});
      },
    );
  }
}

class User {
  User({required this.id, required this.name, required this.tapCount});
  final int id;
  final String name;
  int tapCount;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works perfectly. And I have a question about this case.  But If I have a load more listview (I will add new data when the user scrolls to the end) => what happens with the old list?

Comment: You're talking about a paginated list. So, when you have a list of ten items & you're adding ten new items to the same list, at that moment, we've to transfer the latest list to the older list. It means adding or appending a list.

Comment: If you don't want to write much code, this package is for you. https://pub.dev/packages/infinite_scroll_pagination

Comment: Yeap. I know how to make it work. But in this case, Will 10 older items be rebuilt?

Comment: Yes, the whole list got updated, including their properties like: "list.length".
I can't explain much in the comment section. You could ask this as a separate question if you want.